# how to count total rows in csv using java

Tags: java, opencsv

I have a csv file. I want to write a function in Java which will tell me how many rows are there in csv. Could someone please help me in achieving this.

csv has following format:

```
"Time","Actual","Time","Expected","Time","Status"
"2012-09-01 00:00:00",580.543,"2012-09-01 00:00:00",570.761,"2012-09-01 01:00:00",0
"2012-09-01 01:00:00",646.703,"2012-09-01 01:00:00",672.926,"2012-09-01 02:00:00",0
"2012-09-01 02:00:00",680.705,"2012-09-01 02:00:00",687.784,"2012-09-01 03:00:00",0
"2012-09-01 03:00:00",661.968,"2012-09-01 03:00:00",702.436,"2012-09-01 04:00:00",0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

following function counts the number of line in any file...

```
public int count(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
    byte[] c = new byte[1024];
    int count = 0;
    int readChars = 0;
    boolean empty = true;
    while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
        empty = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
            if (c[i] == '\n') {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
    is.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: this works only if the file ends in a newLine character, otherwise the count is off by 1

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not a generic solution. If a column contains data with line breaks, row count is not equal to the line count.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
     String input;
     int count = 0;
     while((input = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
     {
         count++;
     }

     System.out.println("Count : "+count);
```

Comment: This will count one line too many.

Comment: You can start the `count = -1` as the first line is a header.  You can also ignore blank lines.

Comment: I don't believe in assigning non-necessary values to variables -- actually using the initial 'null' at any point would have been erroneous, so assigning a false/ invented value (when not syntactically necessary) is erroneous -- correct is to declare & leave unassigned. +1 for the BufferedReader solution, though.

Comment: I tried it in a seperate method so only i initialized as null.

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of lines and subtract one. Count how many times you can call BufferedReader.readLine();  You might want to ignore empty lines.

Comment: Minus one line, which are the headers.

Comment: I am assuming from the format.  You can have CSV files without a header.

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine() is probably a superior place to count the lines though, than my suggestion which was regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex Pattern to match newline, and count the matches?

```
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("\\n");
Matcher m = patt.matcher( text);
//
int newlines = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    newlines++;
}
```

Count(newlines) will be one less than how many distinct lines there are. Note that your first line is headers, not data.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read every single line separated by newline if you are sure that field are not splitted in multiple lines.
Else use one of the library mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410538/which-is-the-best-csv-parser-in-java).